# Vestrup Measure and Integration Exercise 5.1.6

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

Let $A \notin \mathcal{L}$. Let $f: (\Bbb{R}, \mathcal{L}) \to (\Bbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$ be given by
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
 x&\text{if}\, x\in A\\
 -x&\text{if}\, x\notin A
\end{cases}.
$$
We want to show that $f$ fails to be $(\mathcal{L}, \mathcal{B})$-measurable, yet $f^{-1}(\{x\}) \in \mathcal{L}$.

---

To prove that $f$ is not $(\mathcal{L}, \mathcal{B})$-measurable, I want to find a Borel set $B$ such that $f^{-1}(B) = A \notin \mathcal{L}$. But I cannot find such a $B$ using the above definition. What I found is if I restrict the domain of $f$ to $[0,1]$ and let $A \subset [0,1]$ with $A \notin \mathcal{L}$, then $f^{-1}((0,\infty)) = \{x \in \Bbb{R} \mid f(x) > 0\} = A \notin \mathcal{L}$, so $f$ is not $(\mathcal{L}, \mathcal{B})$-measurable.

So is the original definition valid or not? If yes, how can I find such a Borel set $B$?

Comment: The sum of two measurable functions is measurable. Let $g(x)=x+f(x).$ If $f$ is measurable then $g$ is measurable. But $g^{-1}\{0\}$ is either $\Bbb R\setminus A$ or $(\Bbb R\setminus A)\cup \{0\}.$ So $g^{-1}\{0\}\not\in\mathcal L.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original definition: "To prove that $f$ is not $(\mathcal{L}, \mathcal{B})$-measurable, I want to find a Borel set $B$ such that $f^{-1}(B) = A \notin \mathcal{L}$." This statement is true.

Solution. Suppose that $f$ is measurable. Hence $f^{-1}((0, \infty))$ is measurable. Hence $(0, \infty) \cap f^{-1}((0, \infty)) $ is measurable. $$x \in (0, \infty) \cap f^{-1}((0, \infty)) \Leftrightarrow (x > 0) \cap (x \in A) \Rightarrow $$  $$(0, \infty) \cap f^{-1}((0, \infty)) = A \cap (0,\infty)$$
Hence $ A \cap (0,\infty)$ is measurable.
Similarly, we prove that  $ A \cap (-\infty, 0)$ is measurable.
Hence $A = (A \cap (0,\infty)) \sqcup ( A \cap (-\infty, 0)) \sqcup (A \cap \{ 0\})$ is measurable since $(A \cap \{ 0\}) \subset \{ 0\}$ is measurable. So we got that $A$ is measurable and got a contradiction.